# .click event work on home page but didn't work and post page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I try to solved this problem but I don't understood where is the error.

I have and footer of all pages a  to the visitors can comeback to the important part of the site whit slow animation.

In [main page](http://boxingday.ch)  any problem that work correctly.

But in post page the animation didn't existe.
[this is an exemple of page with the problem.](http://boxingday.ch/soccerex-grande-messe-du-football-business/)

the code I used for the animation is this:

```
 $(".gotof").click(function (e) {
    var b = $(this).attr("href").substr(1);
 console.log(b);
event.preventDefault();
        $(".wrapper").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + b).offset().top + $(".wrapper").scrollTop()-60 
    }, "slow");
 console.log('e');});
```

First I think is the sibling of the element but no problem in this part.
After I try other functions for scroll to an anchor.
After multiples tests I control if something is not same in the two page but same Js, same plugin.

I don't understand what is the problem.

Please help me.

Comment: Your HTML markup is not valid. Especially the page that doesn't work has a lot of issues. You should fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `event.preventDefault()` - `event` is not defined, `e` is. Change it to `e`, instead of `event`, and it'll probably work. If you had looked in the browser console, you'd seen this. That might not be the error, but it will prevent the rest of the script to run.

Comment: OP says the code executes just fine on the home page.

Comment: That he does, but it doesn't. It just jumps to `#top`- which it also does on the page he linked to.

Comment: What browser are you using? Home page works fine for me with Opera (which is Chrome-based).

Comment: Also neither page gives me any errors in the console for some reason.

Comment: Firefox. Good to have a proper browser when you do debugging ;) But yeah, tested in Chrome, and it does not work at all on the linked page, but works as intended on the home-page, as OP stated (hence why it is important to test in different browsers as well). I just assume anyone working with web uses Firefox with Firebug and other plugins loaded.

Comment: It's the _smart_ assumption, but yeah, I give people too much credit :D